# Pop out from the stack Navigation on react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

This is my `Router navigation setup`. I navigated from `EmployeeList` to `EmployeeCreate` component. I want to back to the EmployeeList when I click a **Create** Button.

```
<Router>
   <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
     <Scene key="auth">
       <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Login" />
     </Scene>

     <Scene key="main">
      <Scene
        onRight={() => Actions.employeeCreate()}
        rightTitle="Add"
        key="employeeList"
        component={EmployeeList}
        title="Employee List"
        initial={true}
      />
      <Scene key="employeeCreate" component={EmployeeCreate} title="Employee Create"/>
     </Scene>
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

I have tried like this. But got an error:

> "There is no route defined for key employeeCreate. Must be one of: 'auth','main'"

```
Actions.employeeCreate({ type: 'reset' });
```

**EmployeeCreate**.**js**

```
onButtonPress() {
    const { name, phone, shift } = this.props;
   this.props.employeeCreate({name, phone, shift: shift || 'Monday'});
 }

export const employeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift }) => {
  return() => {
    Actions.employeeCreate({ type: 'reset' });
  }
};
```

**How could I call employeeList Scene inside main Scene?**

Comment: Can you ping the code of your create button call plz ?

Comment: @GabrielDiez updated. Please check now

Comment: Try Actions.pop() for go back to previous component

Comment: Its worked. Thanks. One more thing. How can i go back to the particular stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For go back to previous component you should use

```
Actions.pop()
```

If you need to go to a specific scene who is present in the group of scenes you are working on. You can call the scene by the key you defined in your Scene

```
Actions.employeeList()
```

If you need to go to an other group of scene you have to call the key of the parent scene

```
Actions.auth()
```